# Cross-browser JavaScript Paste

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, clipboard, paste, execcommand

Earlier the application was getting the contents of clipboard from window.clipboardData.getData('Text'). But this is not supported in firefox and chrome.

For copy, document.execCommand('copy') was invoked to get UI contents to the clipboard. Because document.execCommand('copy') is supported in firefox and chrome it is working there.

Whereas while doing the paste, document.execCommand('paste') is returning false in firefox even though document.queryCommandSupported('paste') is true, document.queryCommandEnabled('paste') is false in firefox and chrome but it is returning true in IE.Is there any way in javascript to make document.execCommand('paste') return true?

There is a button onclick of which it should paste the contents to the UI, In this application basically a table rows are appended from clipboard data.
ClipboradData is captured by trapping ctrl+c ctrl+v events. But I want the access ClipboradData, onclick event or access the clipboard data through document.execCommand('paste'), which is returning false(in firefox and chrome).

```
function paste() {

    var input = document.createElement('TEXTAREA');
    input.setAttribute('name', 'post');
    input.setAttribute('maxlength', 5000);
    input.setAttribute('cols',80);
    input.setAttribute('rows', 40);
    document.body.appendChild (input);
    input.contentEditable = true;
    input.focus();
    if(document.queryCommandEnabled('paste')){
        document.execCommand('paste',false,null);
        result=input.value;
    }   
    document.body.removeChild(input);
    return result;
}
```

Please give me a solution for pasting from clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use document.execCommand('paste') to read the clipboard data from plain javascript for security reasons. You must create a web extension to do that.

Comment: @bnieland If you use Chrome it is true (it using directly its native client), if you use Firefox that it is not going to work.

Comment: I have not tested it, but it seems that Google docs *is* using an extension.